# How do I remove SpatRasters from a list or sprc that have only NaN values

Tags: r, terra, rsi

Minimum example:

```
library(terra)
library(future)
library(rsi)
library(here)

n.cores <- future::availableCores() - 1

f <- system.file("ex/elev.tif", package="terra")
r1 <- rast(f)
r2 <- rast(f)
r3 <- rast(f)
values(r2) <- NA
values(r3) <- 0
r4 <- c(r1, r2, r3)
r5 <- lapply(r4, function(x) project(x, y = 'epsg:32610'), res=1, threads=n.cores)
```

I would like to do something like the following:

```
r6 <- lapply(r5, function(x) ifelse(nrow(unique(values(is.nan(x)))) == 1, -x, x))
```

I am using threads because I have lots of data. I am working with the new rsi package and downloading large amounts of MODIS data. Some of the data retrieved has only NaN, which I might be able to prevent first in the call to `get_stac_data()` but have not found that solution. My question is if there is an efficient way to remove NaN only SpatRasters using terra?

```
Modis_VI <- dir(paste0(here::here("Outputs","Rasters")), full.names=TRUE)
f <- lapply(Modis_VI,
            terra::rast)

f2 <- lapply(f, function(x) project(x, y = 'epsg:32610', threads=n.cores, res=250))
f3 <- lapply(f2, function(x) ifelse(nrow(unique(values(is.nan(x)))) == 1, !x, x))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you trying to `Filter` the list to reduce the number of elements?

```
r6 = Filter(function(r){!all(is.nan(values(r)))}, r5)
```

For your test data this results in `r6` as a list with two elements, dropping one from `r5`. I'm not sure how this could be sped up in parallel though...

Comment: Thank you - this worked. I forgot about this handy function. Very helpful. If needed, I believe I can speed this in parallel using parallel::makeCluster().